# How can I access the items in my string-array resource within my Datasource class?

Tags: arrays, string, android-studio, kotlin, resources

I am trying to create a Map that uses Strings as keys and holds StringArrays as values. I am creating this map inside my Datasource class.

The Strings I would like to use as keys are declared in strings.xml like so:

```
<string-array name="races">
        <item>Archfiend</item>
        <item>Asrai</item>
        <item>Blinkbeast</item>
        <item>Crogoblin</item>
        <item>Demonaga</item>
        <item>Dragonborn</item>
        <item>Dwarf</item>
        <item>Elf</item>
        <item>Fairy</item>
        <item>Gnome</item>
        <item>Grey</item>
        <item>Half-Dragon</item>
        <item>Half-Elf</item>
        <item>Half-Orc</item>
        <item>Half-Troll</item>
        <item>Halfling</item>
        <item>Haud</item>
        <item>Human</item>
        <item>Kodama</item>
        <item>Loralai</item>
        <item>Nekojin</item>
        <item>Parasite</item>
        <item>Satyr</item>
        <item>Slime</item>
        <item>Tiefling</item>
    </string-array>
```

and, as an example, I would like to map the string "Archfiend" to the string-array "archfiend_subraces."

```
<string-array name="archfiend_subraces">
        <item>Aerial</item>
        <item>None</item>
    </string-array>
```

My Datasource class is shown below:

```
package com.example.anime5echaractersheet.data

import android.content.res.Resources
import com.example.anime5echaractersheet.R

class Datasource {

    private val raceList: Array<String> = Resources.getStringArray(R.array.races)

    val subraceMap: Map<String, Int> = mapOf(
        raceList[0] to R.array.archfiend_subraces
    )
}
```

**I am unable to use getStringArray() and I'm not sure why**.

I attempted to use getResources() as well, instead of Resources, but that also seems to be unavailable to me. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve an instance of Resources from a Context instance. You can't just call its functions using the name of the class. So your `DataSource` class needs a `Context` or `Resources` parameter in its constructor. However, I would advise against using String resources as keys, because if your app has translations of the Strings and the user changes their language setting, it will break your app.

I suggest defining all your types and subtype lists in a json file that use unique keys instead of literal values. Then you don't have to do all this hard-coded manual "wiring" of resources to each other. It will make it much easier to edit your content from a single Json file if you want to for example add or remove a certain race. For example:

```json
{
  "races" : [
    "archfiend" {
      "subraces" : [ "ariel", "none" ]
    },
    "asrai",
    ...
  ]
}
```

And then instead of `string-array` resources, use plain `string` resources that use the keys from the json as their names.

```xml
<string name="archfiend">Archfiend</string>
<string name="ariel">Ariel</string>
<string name="none">None</string>
<string name="asrai">Asrai</string>
```

At runtime you can use this helper function to retrieve the actual Strings:

```
fun Context.resourceKeyToString(key: String): String =
    resources.getString(resources.getIdentifier(key, "string", packageName))
```

This is getting off-topic for your question. You can look up tutorials on using Json in Android.